# How to add a space in one iteration of SQL query without effecting the other in my PHP

Tags: php, css, mysql

I need to put a space between two words for a few iterations of my SQL query but I don't want it to happen for every use.

I tried putting margins with CSS, it didn't work. Here is a example of the code i'm working with:

```
<div class="CodeContainer">
    <div class="row">
        <?php
            $query = "
                SELECT 
                    DISTINCT
                        CASE 
                            WHEN code = '1' THEN 'TheOne'
                            WHEN code = '0' THEN 'Zero'
                        END
                FROM 
                    table
                WHERE
                    code IN 
                        (
                            '1', 
                            '0'
                        );
            ";
            $result = mysqli_query($db, $query);

            // But do check if it returned results
            if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0) {
                die("$query returned 0 results, ask admin to check if Filters.php data is correct");
            }

            // Array all the codes the query returned
            $codes = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_NUM);
        ?>
        <div class="column">

                <!-- Start looping through the $codes array -->
                <?php                                       

                    //Count each iteration of $code
                    $codecount = 0;     

                    foreach($codes as $code):   


                        // New column for every 1 iterations 
                        if ($codecount == 1) {                      
                            echo '</div>';                                                              
                            echo '<div class="column">';                
                        }

                        $codecount++;   

                ?>                          
                <label class="CodeCheckbox">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="Code" value="<?php echo $code[0]; ?>" checked>             
                    <div class="CodeLabel"><?php echo $code[0]; ?><!-- This is where I want a specific iteration to have a space --></div>                                                                  
                </label>

            <?php endforeach; ?>            
        </div>                          
    </div>
</div>
```

I expect there to be a space between 'The' and 'One' only when `$code[0]` = `TheOne` between `<div class="CodeLabel">` but no other iterations of `$code[0]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're wanting different behavior for one specific condition, it seems like you could just check for that condition on output and modify the text if the condition is met rather than trying to do it in the query.

```
<?php echo $code[0] == 'TheOne' ? 'The One' : $code[0]; ?>
```

I may have misunderstood what you meant by "I don't want it to happen for every use", though. I assumed you meant other uses of the same query.

Comment: This worked thanks! In my actual work I had to do this for 3 out of 6 iterations. So I just copy and pasted that line 6 times.